# How do I store a discord bot token in a .json file?

Tags: discord.py

Current Code

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>')

@bot.command()
async def help(ctx):
    await ctx.send('This command hasn't been started yet.')

bot.run('token')
```

Discord.py Rewrite
Python 3.9

Comment: What do you want to achieve, exactly? Have a different prefix per server and store that association in a `.json`-file? You'll need to add a few more details if you want us to be able to help you

Comment: Well, I'm not good at explaining things, but I would like to do this in discord.py (this guide is for discord.js, but i've seen discord.py bots do this too) https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/configuration-files.html#implementing-your-config-file

Comment: I would like to store my bots prefix and token in a single .json file on discord.py

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set a json file such as `config.json` with content like

```json
{
    "TOKEN": "AD213.213.1DA",
    "PREFIX": "!"

}
```

Make sure to use [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)

```py
import json

with open('config.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    token = data["TOKEN"]
    prefix = data["PREFIX"]
```